# I Need Account Statement Table in PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

Please, I need expert help. I am new here.

I want to display a table that will show the `Balance = Amount - Cost` as shown below, but the table should be reducing the amount based on the cost deducted. Table one is what I got from my code, the first row was OK but see table 2 as the expected table.

```
ID         Amount   COST   Balance
P20/0050   10000    2000   8000
P20/0050   1000     9000   1000
P20/0050   4000     6000  -2000
```

The first row was ok, but subsequently, it should set amount to Balance and so on.

Expected table

```
ID         Amount   COST   Balance
P20/0050   10000    2000   8000
P20/0050   8000     9000   -1000
P20/0050   1000     6000  -5000
```

My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, card_number, Fullname, Phone, Sickness, Treatment,Amount, Cost_of_treatment, 
        Amount-Cost_of_treatment AS Balance, Transaction_Date, Blood_group FROM treatment WHERE 
        card_number='$card_number'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a database that supports window functions, this is as simple as a window sum:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    card_number, 
    Fullname, 
    Phone, 
    Sickness, 
    Treatment,
    Amount, 
    Cost_of_treatment, 
    SUM(Amount - Cost_of_treatment) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Transaction_Date) AS Balance, 
    Transaction_Date, 
    Blood_group 
FROM treatment 
WHERE card_number = ?
```

Comment: Thanks,  what is your personal mail may be i can send the result to you. It was giving another results entirely.